# drawing trail to location on gps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I am failry new at using the gps function.  What my code does is it allows the user to select a point on the map, and it drops a marker.  I also want it to draw a trail to the selected point to guide the user to the location.

I am not really sure how to go about doing so, if sombody can maybe help me find a tutorial, of some sort that would be greatly appreciated.

```
  OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(
                                            touchedpoint, "AYO", "Whats good yo");
                                    CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d,
                                            CampusMap.this);
                                    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                                    overlayList.add(custom);
```

Comment: No this issue still has not been solved

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MyLocationOverlay`, it shows you compass and location ;)